# Rational or integer solution to simultaneous equation

Tags: number-theory

$(w+4m)^4+(w-4m)^2(4m^2+16)^2=p^2$

$(4m)^2-(w)^2=q^2$

where, $w=(m^2-4)$

And  (p,q,m) are rational or integer's.

I tried, $[m=2]$ & I got $[q=(8)]$, which satisfy's the second equation, but does not satisfy's the first. 
If somebody could do a numerical search, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'but does not satisfy's the first'?
The variable is $p$ in the first equation and $q$ in the second equation.

Comment: We need both simultaneous equations to made squares. While in the second equation for variable 'm' =2, we get q=2. After substituting for 'm' =2, in the first equation we get (p^2)=17*(64)^2, which is not a square as requested in the question.